# Clearing browsing data "from the past hour" seems to clear more

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I've been logged into SuperUser for probably months now. And I disabled autoplay in YouTube many months ago. Both of those states are stored via cookies.

Yesterday I cleared the following browsing data:

- Browsing history
- "Cookies and other site and plugin data"

... for the time range "the past day".

Now I see that I've been logged out of SU, YouTube autoplay is back on, Facebook is telling me about its usage of cookies again, etc.

*So I believe older cookies have been lost too.* Not all of them, it seems, but a lot.

**Any idea why this has happened?**

Comment: Probably cookies that got touched/updated in the last day by those websites ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies can get updated (not updated actually, overwritten). Past ones get replaced by new ones. Even if you logged in months back, it's possible the new cookies are taking care of the login info and autoplay.

Clearing the data from the past day hence, **can** wipe non recent settings.

The browsing data time period is just an estimate. You can correctly estimate it for web pages which were cached, and even that cache has a lifespan. Beyond that, even websites you have been visiting for months might not qualify as months old data on the hard drive.